# Hibernate Envers Audit Query- retrieve only the most recent revision for all entities

Tags: hibernate-envers, spring-data-envers

I would like to retrieve the all recent versions of all entities( i.e. everything in Database) that has changed recently.
Following query fetch revisions of specific entity "MyEntity"

queryObject = auditReader.createQuery().forRevisionsOfEntity(MyEntity.class, false, true).addOrder(AuditEntity.revisionNumber().desc())

But I need a mechanism to fetch records for all entities irrespective of particular entity type.

Answer (score 0):

Look into `org.hibernate.envers.track_entities_changed_in_revision`.

This setting causes a join-table to be created against the revision-entity where a string-based set of entity names will be tracked for each revision number.  With this information, you should be able to build necessary queries using the `AuditReader#createQuery()` API to iterate all the changes.

In pseudo code, it would be something like:

```
List<Number> revisions = // create AuditQuery to get all revision numbers
for ( Number revision : revisions ) {
  DefaultTrackingModifiedEntitiesRevisionEntity revisionEntity = // create query to get revision entity
  for ( String entityName : revisionEntity.getModifiedEntityNames() ) {
    // create query based on entityName + revisionNumber
  }
}
```

Comment: How to get all revision numbers. Should I explicitly query revchanges table for same or is there any implicit method provided by enver framework ?

Comment: @Satyam this can help:  https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#envers-querying-revision-entities